# Linux Boot Problem

Tags: linux, boot

I have a **Dell OptiPlex 7040** with an **NVME M.2** startup volume.  Quick, when it works.  I rebooted recently and it didn't come up.  I updated the **BIOS**, because the logs told me it was bad:

```
# BAD BIOS from `Journalctl -xb`
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: MAR: [Firnuare Bug]: No firnuare reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x00000000dd800000-0x00000000dfffffffl, contact By
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken: bad RuRR (0x0000000OdaB00000-0x0000000OdfffffffI
                                        BIOS vendor: Dell Inc.: Ver: 1.4.9: Product Version:
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base Oxfed91000 IOMMU 1
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: DMAR-IR: HET id 0 under DRHD base Oxfed91000
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: DMAR-IR: Queued invalidation will be enabled to support »Zapic and Intr-remapping.
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: DMAR-IR: Enabled IRQ remapping in xZapic mode
Jul 06 18:30:24 server_f.project33.ca kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled bu BIOS.
Jul 06 18:30:25 server_f.project33.ca kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Lsdb] Mo Caching mode page found
Jul 06 18:30:25 server_f.project33.ca kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Lsdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul 06 18:30:26 server_f.project33.ca systemdl11: Failed to mount /boot.
Jul 06 18:30:26 server_f.project33.ca systemd1]: Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
Jul 06 18:30:26 server_f. project33.ca kernel: device-mapper: core: Cannot calculate initial queue limits
Jul 06 18:30:26 server_f.project33.ca systemdl1l: Failed to start LUM event activation on device 8:2
```

So new firmware, and the same error is happening.  Something to do with a `LUM event activation on device 8:2`:

```
## New BIOS OptiPlex_7040_1.23.0.exe
## Startup:

...
DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[ 2.8781271 1915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:124:DDI E/PHY E] is disabled/in
DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[FAILED] Failed to start LUM event activation on device 8:2.
See "systemctl status lum2-puscan08:2.service" for details.
[ 2.879550] 1915 0000:00:02.0: [drml Finished loading MC firmware 1915/skl_d
mc_ver1_27 .bin (v1.27)
[ 2.885725] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.8 on minor B
You are in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "exit"
to boot into default mode.
[ 2.887900] ACPI: Video Device (GFX0] (multi-head: yes rom: no post: no)
[ 2.8882081 input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PMPDABB:BB/L
NXVIDED:00/input/input16
[ 2.8883351 snd hda_intel aBB0:00:1f .3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_co
mponent _bind_ops [i9151)
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue) :
2.899201] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL oma in vackage
2.8992191 intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
2.8992211 intel rapl _common: Found RAPL domain uncore
2.899222] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
...
^d
[root@server_f ~]# systemctl status lum2-puscan@@:2.service
Unit lum2-puscan@8:2.service could not be found.
[root@server_f ~]#
```

I have no clue how to get around this.  I don't remember changing anything with users or anything significant, just `scripts` for port sniffing.

How I can fix this?

The `OS` is brand new and was functioning fine.  Seeing that some feedback was past the BIOS part and into loading the OS, I think this is more of an OS thing, which is `AlmaLinux 8.6`.  Cheers

Update:  These are the results post-`BIOS` update.  Highlighted red in the startup post-`POST` output:

```
Jul 07 16:11:54 server_f.local kernel: x86/epu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Jul 07 16:11:56 server_f.project33.ca systemd1l: Failed to mount /boot.
Jul 07 16:11:56 server_f.project33.ca systemdl1l: Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
Jul 07 16:11:56 server_f project33.ca kernel: device-mapper: core: Cannot calculate initial queue limits
Jul 07 16:11:56 server_f .project33.ca systemdl1l: Failed to start LUM event activation on device B:2.
Jul 07 16:12:06 server_f.project33.ca systemdI11: Failed to mount /boot.
Jul 07 16:12:06 server_f.project33.ca systemdl1l: Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
```

Startup messages:

```
FAILED] Failed to start LVM event activation on device 8:2.
See "systemctl status lvm2-puscan@B:2.service' for details.
[ OK  ] Mounted /home

[rootlserver_f ~]# systemctl status lvm2-puscan@8:2.service
• lvm2-puscan8:2. service - LUM event activation on device 8:2
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lvm2-puscan@.service; static: vendor preset: disabled)
Active: Palled (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-07-07 16:27:46 EDT: 57s ago
Docs: man: puscan(8)
Main PID: 889 (code=exited, status=5)

Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[889]:  puscan8891 UG rl not using quick activation.
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[8891:  WARNING: Device /dev/sda2 has size of 486297600 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PU size of 998115328 sectors. Was device resized?
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[8891:  WARMING: One or more devices used as PUs in UG rl have changed sizes.
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[8891:  device-mapper: reload loctl on (253:4) failed: Invalid argument  
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[8891:  device-mapper: reload ioctl on (253:4) failed: Invalid argument
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[8891:  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "rl" now active
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f.project33.ca lvm[889]:  puscan[8891 rl: autoactivation failed.
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f .project33.ca systemd1]:  lumZ-puscan08:2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status-5/NOTINSTALLED
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f .project33.ca systemd[11: lum2-puscan@8:2.service: Failed with result *exit-cade"
Jul 07 16:27:46 server_f .project33.ca systemdl11: Failed to start LUM event activation on device 8:2.

[root&server_f ~] lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN  RM    SIZE       RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0     0     447G      0   disk
|-sda1                      8:1     0       1G      0   part
|-sda2                      8:2     0     231.9G    0   part
  |-r1-swap               253:3     0      15.7G    0   lvm
nvmeOn1                   251:0     0     232.9G    0   disk
|-nume0n1p1               259:1     0       1G      0   part
|-nume0n102               259:2     0     231.9G    0   part
  |-almalinux server_f-root.   253:0     0       70G     0   lvm   /
  |-almalinux server_f-swap   253:1     0      15.7G    0   lvm   [SWAP]
  |-almalinux server_f-home   253:2     0     146.2G    0   lvm   /home
```

Looks like `sda2` has problems.  So I took it out and formatted it on another box, same problem: `Failed to mount /boot.`  Took the drive out of the box, so only the `nvme` boot volume is in there, same problem.  It's not mounting `/boot` for some reason.

```
[rootlfuf ~]# dmesg | grep -i mount
[0.019538] Mount-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, vmalloc)
[0.019726] Moumtpoint-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, umalloc)
[1.825407] XPS (dm-@): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[1.834948] XFS (dm-8): Ending clean mount
[2.322309] XTS (numeßn1p1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[2.343868] XFS (numeßn1p1): Corruption warning: Metadata has LSN (1:3869) ahead of current LSM (1:3835). Please unmount and run x's repair (>= V4.3) to resolve.
[2.344044] XFS (numeßn1p1): log mount/recovery failed: error -22
[2.344227] XTS (numeln1p1) : log mount failed
[2.679073] XFS (dm-2) : Mounting VS Filesystem
[2.698961] XPS (dm-2): Ending clean mount
[6.938996] XFS (nume0n1p1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[6.960104] XFS (nume0n1p1): Corruption warning: Metadata has LSN (1:3869) ahead of current LSN (1:3835). Please unmount and run x's repair (>= V4.3) to resove.
[6.960142] XFS (nume0n1p1) :log mount/recovery failed: error -22
[6.960346] XTS (nume@n1p1): log mount failed
```

As it stands Friday morning, bootable, with a new storage `SSD` mounted:

```
/dev/mapper/almalinux_server_f-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 1
# UUID=83cfc468-ecce-4188-aef4-e53cea90655a /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/almalinux_server_f-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/almalinux_server_f-swap none                    swap    defaults        0 0

# A backup drive since added
UUID=f6db13da-ef71-4252-aab4-4f51f90ce6f7   /mnt/backups    ext4    defaults    0   2
```

`/boot` is not mounting:

```
 lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0   477G  0 disk
└─sda1                   8:1    0   477G  0 part /mnt/backups
nvme0n1                259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0     1G  0 part
└─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0 231.9G  0 part
  ├─almalinux_fuf-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─almalinux_fuf-swap 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─almalinux_fuf-home 253:2    0 146.2G  0 lvm  /home
```

Looks like the `log` was bad, so a modified repair was needed:

```
[2022_Jul_8 06:25:18 rich@fuf ~] sudo xfs_repair -L /dev/nvme0n1p1
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
Phase 2 - using internal log
        - zero log...
ALERT: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which is being
destroyed because the -L option was used.
        - scan filesystem freespace and inode maps...
        - found root inode chunk
Phase 3 - for each AG...
        - scan and clear agi unlinked lists...
        - process known inodes and perform inode discovery...
        - agno = 0
        - agno = 1
        - agno = 2
        - agno = 3
        - process newly discovered inodes...
Phase 4 - check for duplicate blocks...
        - setting up duplicate extent list...
        - check for inodes claiming duplicate blocks...
        - agno = 0
        - agno = 1
        - agno = 2
        - agno = 3
Phase 5 - rebuild AG headers and trees...
        - reset superblock...
Phase 6 - check inode connectivity...
        - resetting contents of realtime bitmap and summary inodes
        - traversing filesystem ...
        - traversal finished ...
        - moving disconnected inodes to lost+found ...
Phase 7 - verify and correct link counts...
Maximum metadata LSN (1:3869) is ahead of log (1:2).
Format log to cycle 4.
done
[2022_Jul_8 06:25:27 rich@fuf ~] sudo mount -a
[2022_Jul_8 06:25:43 rich@fuf ~] lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0   477G  0 disk
└─sda1                   8:1    0   477G  0 part /mnt/backups
nvme0n1                259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0 231.9G  0 part
  ├─almalinux_fuf-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─almalinux_fuf-swap 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─almalinux_fuf-home 253:2    0 146.2G  0 lvm  /home

/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="df549f07" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="83cfc468-ecce-4188-aef4-e53cea90655a" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="df549f07-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="i75kzm-ywmo-kblc-qVub-OAXc-oKPN-hmMtne" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="df549f07-02"
/dev/sda1: UUID="f6db13da-ef71-4252-aab4-4f51f90ce6f7" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cb238e81-b4d2-ba41-8a4c-19f01ea2cfd5"
/dev/mapper/almalinux_fuf-root: UUID="d0aab1dc-6d0a-4a36-b6ff-65853f73490f" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/almalinux_fuf-swap: UUID="fb98b19f-a542-416b-8708-a397f2e5ca3b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/almalinux_fuf-home: UUID="f74e1ac0-2e82-430a-a588-169d4f487cf5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs"
```

Comment: (1) Does the BIOS log still report those errors after the update? (2) Did you do `journalctl -xb` in emergency mode?

Comment: @Philippos Just updated the OP.  Same stuff, but no mention of a bad `BIOS`.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing for possibly unrelated typo pb, just surprised reading **Firnuare Bug]: No firnuare**

Comment: @MC68020 Ya this is all taken from a `MacOS` picture `OCR`, so there are some misspelled words in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Firmware Bug]` messages are usually more like open letters from kernel developers to system firmware developers: "Please follow the specifications so we don't have to keep inventing dirty workarounds." Unless the problem appeared immediately after a BIOS update, those are unlikely to be the root cause of your problems.

However, this might be:

```
Jul 06 18:30:26 server_f.project33.ca systemdl11: Failed to mount /boot.
```

There seems to be something wrong with your `/boot` filesystem, which derails the normal system start-up process. Since `/boot` is only needed by the bootloader and kernel updates, you could temporarily comment out `/boot` from `/etc/fstab` and see if you can get the system to come up to something resembling a normal state - if successful, it would make troubleshooting the `/boot` issues much easier.

It looks like your NVMe system disk might be somewhat corrupted, or perhaps starting to die. What happens when a SSD device starts to fail is unfortunately not quite as predictable as with traditional HDDs: when SSDs fail, they sometimes just up and die completely with no real warning signs.

The fact that your NVMe SSD still mostly works seems encouraging, but in your position I would be *really* worried about any data that is not backed-up to some other media. If the system contains anything remotely important, I would recommend finding a way to plug that NVMe SSD as a second disk to some other computer, and backing up everything you still can access **as soon as possible** before doing anything else with it.

To evaluate the health of your NVMe SSD, you might try running `smartctl -x /dev/nvme0` as root, and seeing what it says after the `=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===` heading.

If that command is not available, `nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0` should provide essentially the same data, and `nvme error-log /dev/nvme0` might provide more details on a number of most recently detected errors, if there are any.

---

So, by temporarily commenting out `/boot` from `/etc/fstab` seems to have allowed the system to come up. (Seeing your `/etc/fstab` as it exists now would be helpful here: it would minimize the need for guesswork.)

The message `Failed to start LVM event activation on device 8:2` refers to a block device with major device number 8 and minor number 2, which is `/dev/sda2`. That seems to have a separate issue, and since you've already removed that disk from the system, that message should not reoccur any more.

Note the error message:
`XFS (nvme0n1p1): Corruption warning: Metadata has LSN (1:3869) ahead of current LSN (1:3835). Please unmount and run xfs_repair (>= V4.3) to resolve.`

This seems to indicate that according to `/etc/fstab` your `/boot` is/was directly on partition `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, **NOT** as a LVM logical volume.

Assuming `nvme0n1p1` is your `/boot`, now that you have the system running and `/boot` unmounted, you could do what this message suggests, and first run `xfs_repair -V` to verify the repair tool version is 4.3.0 or greater, and if it is, run `xfs_repair /dev/nvme0n1p1`.

It might tell you:

```
ERROR: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which needs to be replayed. 
Mount the filesystem to replay the log, and unmount it before re-running xfs_repair. 
If you are unable to mount the filesystem, then use the -L option to destroy the log and attempt a repair.
Note that destroying the log may cause corruption — please attempt a mount of the filesystem before doing this.
```

If so, then try mounting `/boot`, just in case `xfs_repair` did manage to fix something before printing out that message. If you cannot mount the filesystem (as previous attempts certainly haven't worked), do as the message says and run `xfs_repair -L /dev/nvme0n1p1`.

In the `blkid` output, `TYPE="LVM2_member` refers to a LVM physical volume (PV for short). It is not a filesystem and cannot be mounted as such, but it can be a container for one or more filesystems, or parts of them. Your `/dev/nvme0n1p2` partition should show as `TYPE="LVM2_member"` as it contains your root filesystem, swap area and `/home` filesystem, but apparently not `/boot`.

Filesystem UUIDs don't change by itself: to change them, you would need to either reformat the partition or LVM logical volume using `mkfs` (effectively losing all existing data in it), or using a filesystem-specific tool to assign a new UUID to the filesystem. Therefore, the UUID for `/boot` in `/etc/fstab` should not need changing, unless the `/etc/fstab` itself is corrupted, or you've previously done something to the `/boot` filesystem you're not telling us.

---

**If** `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is showing up as `TYPE="LVM2_member"` too, then that would mean you had overwritten your `/boot` filesystem with a `pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1p1` command. If true, that would certainly explain the corruption.

Anyway, if the above-mentioned `xfs_repair` procedure fails to fix the filesystem so it can be mounted, the last resort would be to rebuild your `/boot` filesystem from scratch.

This procedure will obviously make the system unbootable until it's successfully completed, so don't reboot in the middle of it.
First reformat the corrupted `/boot` filesystem with `mkfs.xfs /dev/nvme0n1p1` (don't make typos, this is destructive!), then use `lsblk -o +UUID /dev/nvme0n1p1` to view its new UUID, re-enable the `/boot` entry in `/etc/fstab` and change its UUID to the new one, then `mount /boot`.

After that, use your package manager to **reinstall** any currently-installed kernel packages: the package management tool should have a specific option that effectively tells it "yes, your database says this package is already installed, but rewrite its files back into place anyway, to replace any missing files and overwrite possibly corrupted ones".

Once that is done, reinstall your bootloader with e.g. `grub2-install /dev/nvme0n1`. Verify your `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` exists and contains your installed kernel versions; if necessary, run `grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to rebuild the configuration. At this point, your system should be bootable again.

Comment: `Critical Warning: 0x00, Unsafe Shutdowns: 28, No Errors Logged`  So commenting out the `fstab` `/boot` volume, brought it up.  What do I do now?  Is that entry providing the wrong `UUID` for that `volume`?

Comment: So the `/boot` volume is commented out, and I get nothing back from `blkid`.  I thought that `UUID` needed updating, but I can't move forward this way.  I have completed `lsblk` showing me `UUID` entries (on a USB `recovery` boot), but I'm not understanding which one I should be using for `/boot`.  I have `-root`, `-home` and `-swap` all on `/dev/mapper/`.  Also, the `NVME` entry of `TYPE="LVM2_member"`, where the `/boot` lives.  Should I use that `UUID` in `fstab`?

Comment: Please see my edit above: this was too complicated to handle in comments.

Comment: Bingo, we're up.  Wow.  Thank you so much.  I entered all the last reads in the OP.

Comment: Adding the backup drive was a good move too, just remember to make use of it :-) If you didn't already uncomment `/boot` in `/etc/fstab`, do it before the next reboot, so you won't run into trouble when the next kernel update arrives.

Comment: FYI the machine lost it's marbles and `xfs_repair` won't help (`couldn't initialize XFS library`).  Somehow the `boot` volume moved itself to `sda` instead of my intended `nvme0n1`.  Strange things.  But, full backup and an opportunity to start from scratch.